# Can the electric force lift heavy bodies?

Tags: electrostatics, estimation, coulombs-law

We all know the experience that consists of rubbing a plastic pen in one's hair and then using the pen to "animate" some little pieces of paper.
By rubbing the pen, you pull the electrons off it, so it gets a positive charge. And when you approach the pen, which is now charged, close to the pieces of papers, the papers stick together.

I had the same experience with a mosquito. I was able to lift him with the electric force. I used a plastic pen whose the mass is $5.0\times 10^{-3} \;\text{kg}$ to lift a mosquito whose the average mass is around $1.5\times 10^{-6} \;\text{kg}$.

So I calculated (with proportionality) that with a pen weighing around $233 \;\text{tonnes}$, we would lift a man of $70 \;\text{kg}$.

It is possible?

Comment: Interesting - you'll have to rub your 233-tonne pen on someone's hair!

Comment: If a 70kg man climbs stairs, it is in fact electric forces lifting 70kg. Every force in our daily life is either gravity, electrostatic, or a relativistic correction over the electrostatic (it is called magnetic) force.

Comment: I don't know about the *electric* force, but [*the* force sure can](https://youtu.be/E3-CpzZJl8w?t=172) :-).

Comment: @fraxinus That is the boring way to think about it. I want to see 233 tonne pen rubbed on someone's hair.

Comment: Re "We all know the experience...", I doubt that's true.  I for one have never generated static electricity that way, nor had I ever heard of anyone doing it.  Then there are all the people with short haircuts or shaved heads :-)

Comment: I've never used a plastic pen, but I have used balloons to generate static electricity. (Not recently though, for reasons that are obvious from my profile pic.) Balloons are good because once charged they will stick to the wall for a short while.

Comment: The laws of physics don't scale that way.  A microscopic spec of pollen can fly through the air even though it's not remotely shaped like an airfoil.  The same geometric shape scaled up to the size of a human would not float in the air.  Miniature RC aircraft have wildly different flight dynamics compared to large airliners.  Flies can walk on walls, but nothing the size of a walrus could ever do that.  Insects can walk on water, but a goat cannot.  Onion cells contain more pressure than a steam engine boiler.  Changing the size of a thing radically alters how physics works.

Comment: Consider that electrostatics operate on surfaces, which scale as the square of the linear dimension.  The mass of an object scales as the cube of its linear dimension, however.  Cubes always beat squares - welcome to a universe with three spatial dimensions.

Comment: @fraxinus : "it is in fact electric forces lifting 70kg" - maybe this statement is defensible, but it seems at least misleading as it ignores exchange interaction, which is crucial for support reaction.

Comment: Electromagnetic force - as opposed to electrostatic force - includes good ole electromagnets that you see all over the place in industry whenever you want to separate iron from non-iron, or move loose piles of it onto larger loose parts.

Comment: "So I calculated (with proportionality) that with a pen weighing around 233tonnes, we would lift a man of 70kg.". YES. If you can bring the 233 tonne pen as close tot he 70kg man, as you could bring he 5g pen to the 1.5mg mosquito. (center-of-body distances, please). You cannot do that, so NO.

Comment: Who is lifting the 233 tonne pen? Another pen? :)

Answer (score 18):

Unless I miscalculated, this does not seem possible for the following reason.

Let us assess the electric field required to suspend a man with a mass of $m=70kg$. For simplicity, let us consider a plane capacitor with the plate area of $A=1m^2$, which seems reasonable for "one side of a [human body](https://www.medicinenet.com/body_surface_area/definition.htm#:%7E:text=The%20%22normal%22%20body%20surface%20area,for%20adult%20men%3A%201.9%20m2)". The force $F$ between the plates of the capacitor [is](https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Electricity_and_Magnetism/Book%3A_Electricity_and_Magnetism_(Tatum)/05%3A_Capacitors/5.12%3A__Force_Between_the_Plates_of_a_Plane_Parallel_Plate_Capacitor) $\frac{\epsilon_0 A V^2}{2 x^2}=\frac{\epsilon_0 A E^2}{2}$, where $\epsilon_0=8.85\cdot 10^{-12}F/m$, $V$ is the potential difference between the plates, $x$ is the distance between the plates, $E$ is the electric field inside the capacitor. If $F=mg\approx 686N$, we obtain $E=\sqrt{\frac{2 m g}{A\epsilon_0}}\approx 1.24\cdot 10^7 V/m$, whereas [electric breakdown in atmospheric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_breakdown#Gases) air takes place when electric field exceeds $3\cdot 10^6 V/m$.

EDIT(7/30/2021): @EdL asked good questions in a comment:

> So what would happen instead, would the capacitor discharge through
> the air?

Yes.

> Could you do the same electrostatics question with the mosquito to
> compare what field is required for that?

So let us assume that the mosquito has the following [size and weight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mosquito): 4mm and 5mg. Let us assume that the mosquito has a square shape in a plan (this may look silly, but one can make a different assumption and calculate - note the square root in the formula), so the area is $1.6\cdot 10^{-5}m^2$. Substituting this data in the above formula, one obtains $E\approx 8.32\cdot 10^5 V/m$.

Comment: So what would happen instead, would the capacitor discharge through the air? 
Could you do the same electrostatics question with the mosquito to compare what field is required for that?

Comment: @EdL : Please see the EDIT.

Comment: So... this could work in vacuum?

Comment: @Vilx- : I am not sure, one would need to review the breakdown conditions for vacuum. The 70-kg man may not be happy about being placed in vacuum, but, as they say, a properly restrained patient does not need any anesthesia :-)

Answer (score 5):

> So I calculated (with proportionality) that with a Bic Pen weighing
> arround 233 tones, we would lift a men of 70kg.

The magnitude of the electrostatic force the pen exerts on the paper, mosquito, or a man, created by rubbing the pen has nothing to do with the mass of the pen.  The force only depends on the net charge acquired at the surface of the pen due to the rubbing. Adding more mass without increasing the rubbing surface area would not increase the net charge and therefore would not increase the electrostatic force.

Whether or not that electrostatic force is capable of causing the paper, mosquito or man to accelerate towards the pen depends on Newtons second law;

$$F_{E}=ma$$

Where $F_E$ is the electrostatic force due to the net charge on the pen  and $m$ is the mass of the paper, mosquito, or man. As others have pointed out, in order to lift a man the strength of the electric field would have to be extremely high.

Hope this helps.

Comment: A pen with more mass would have a larger capacity to store excess charge, wouldn't it?

Comment: Not necessarily since the rubbing that causes the build up of charge occurs at the surface

Comment: In any case why don’t you post an answer with proof that the electrostatic force is proportional to the mass of the pen as posited by the OP and I will gladly concur

Comment: Sorry for not being clearer. I was asking about the *capacity* to store more charge. Couldn't something with more mass be able to store more charge, and hence it could lead to a larger field. I'm genuinely asking, not critiquing.

Comment: So would it be possible to get enough charge into the pen to create enough force to life tha man?

Comment: Thank you a lot. Indeed I thought that the magnitude of the electrostatic force the pen exerts on the paper, mosquito, or a man, created by rubbing the pen had something to do with the mass of the pen... So we would need the electrostatic force to be equal to his weight, or 700N for lift the man. But the problem is that required a very hight fiel electric...

Comment: @BioPhysicist I could be wrong, but I thought the triboelectric efffect was as surface phenomenon.  Electrons are stripped away from atoms at the surface of one material and added to the surface of another due to friction. Since the materials are usually insulators, electrons are normally tightly bound to the atoms. I wouldn't think electrons in the interior of the material would also be removed. So I would think making a material thicker (increasing mass) without changing the surface area being rubbed would increase the net charge stored. But like I said, I could be wrong.

Comment: @BioPhysicist Also, I see I have gotten a down vote.

Comment: @Newgate I explained the reason I believe the electrostatic force does not depend on the mass to BioPhysicist. As far as the electrostatic force needed to lift a man goes, that would indeed require a very large electric field. To be honest, I don't have a feel for the magnitude of the electrostatic force due to the triboelectric effect.

Comment: @BobD I don't think this answer is not useful, so no downvote from me. I'll give a +1 instead though :) Your point is valid; when we say "more mass" we don't necessarily mean "more surface area." I suppose the OP would need to clarify, but it's not a huge deal.

Comment: @BobD, the downvote is for me - I do not see how the answer helps OP. Nothing is outright wrong in there, but at the least add a napkin calculation which shows whether it is possible (or under which circumstances) to create enough force...

Answer (score 4):

It could be possible, but unlikely due to the strength of the electric field involved$^1$.

The electric field is proportional to the amount charge and does not depend on the mass of any of the bodies.

If you wanted to lift a man who's mass is $70kg$ using electrostatic forces,  you would need the electrostatic force to be equal to his weight, or $$F_E=70g\approx 700N$$

$^1$ The electric potential difference generated by such a huge collection of charge, may exceed the breakdown voltage for air. At that point the charge will rapidly cross the boundary between the two objects and quickly neutralise the system.

Comment: "The electric field is proportional to the amount charge and does not depend on the mass of any of the bodies." Thanks for that response I thought the electric field was proportional to the mass of an object.

Comment: That's OK. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

In principle it is possible but in practice it is extremely difficult.

The problem is that the field strength required to lift any significant weight is extremely high and arcing or breakdown takes place, collapsing the field.

The principle was once studied for hovercraft and VTOL aircraft, but the voltage needed to attain any height was extreme, the field gradient before breakdown still allowed only modest weights, and even if it could have been achieved the risk of electrocution to anybody underneath would have been far too great. I recall an SF story with such vehicles in, but the idea stopped there.

What has been achieved is the use of electrostatic forces to accelerate air, creating thrust for [ion-propelled aircraft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ion-propelled_aircraft). Light and flimsy VTOL models with vertical ion thrust have lifted-off and hovered, but they trailed wires back down to the heavy voltage generator on the ground. MIT also recently made a model fixed-wing plane, the [MIT EAD Airframe Version 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIT_EAD_Airframe_Version_2), sustain flight, with onboard horizontal ion thrust generation and more efficient conventional aerodynamic lift. But the model did not have surplus thrust for takeoff, it had to be launched.

Comment: "Light and flimsy VTOL models with vertical ion thrust" - A once-somewhat-notable antigravity device is actually this. I don't remember the details and Google keeps talking about (supposed) actual military tech, but the the gist is an extremely simple air ionizer kinetic toy that wouldn't work in vacuum and doubled as a significant safety hazard while on.

Comment: @JohnDvorak I have now fixed the link to the Wikipedia article on Ion-propelled aircraft. It outlines the anti-gravity pseudoscience and a couple of genuine VTOL models. The military fantasising is beneath even Wikipedia.

Answer (score 2):

A relatively massive object has been levitated with electrostatic forces.

Gravity Probe B used fused quartz spheres about the size of ping-pong balls. These were designed not only to be centred by electrostatic forces in orbit, needing only fractions of a volt, but also to be levitated in the lab in 1g gravity for testing. This needed about 1500 V across the 0.001" clearance between sphere and housing electrodes, in a vacuum of course.

I'll see if I can find some links to some design papers, please feel free to beat me to it!